# Is python "str is bytes" equivalent to sys.version_info test?

Tags: python

Is it correct to use

```
if str is bytes: ...
```

instead of

```
if sys.version_info < (3,): ...
```

to distinguish python2 from python3?  Especially when the version dependent code is required precisely because of the possibility that str is not unicode, the former sometimes seems clearer to me (and avoids an often gratuitous import sys), yet I've never seen python code which uses this test.  Is "str is bytes" true only as a quirk of version 2 CPython, or is it guaranteed in all python2s?

Comment: You and I have wildly different definitions for "clearer".

Comment: ["Python 2.6 adds `bytes` as a synonym for the `str` type"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3112-byte-literals).  So it looks like this is not just an implementation detail.  It's still very confusing.  Python imports are cheap, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: that history suggests that it's _not_ equivalent, because `str is bytes` will only work in >= 2.6, and the question asked about distinguishing python _2_ from python 3.  `version_info` was introduced in 2.0. ;-)

Comment: @Mephy: Okay, I'm chastened; sys.version_info is certainly the very definition of the difference between python 2 and 3, and I'll use it.  My reasoning was that `PY2 = str is bytes` amounts to duck-typing the whole environment.  Subsequent branches don't really care if it's called python 2 or 3, only whether str is going to be treated as bytes.  But I bow to the will of the voters.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: This link answers my question; make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `sys.version_info < (3,)` to tell readers that you're trying to identify the python2 case.